# Horizontal Paging Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-gridview, horizontal-scrolling

I am relatively new to android.

I have to design an Activity that has a 2 * 4 grid.

Each grid item will have an image view and a text view

On swiping left or right the user will move to a different page but the UI will remain the same.

Just the data set to the grid will change.

I want the number of pages to be configurable.

Also I want to reuse the same xml file for UI instead of creating two new xml files for the other 2 pages.

Which is the best possible way and the most efficient way to implement this and any examples on how to do this ? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit too open-ended (you may get flagged by someone) and there are several ways you could go about achieving this. To help me better understand what you're trying to do, can you perhaps draw a diagram of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `ViewPager` with `Fragment`. You can see in this example https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), each page (probably [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)) containing a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with an [Adapter.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

The fragment code, layout file and adapter implementation would be identical for every page. You just need to pass in the respective data to display to each page.